# Swift app crashing when setting property in main queue

Tags: ios, swift, exception, properties

I am using a property setters and didSet() values to set a "percent complete" property.  All property access is done in the main queue, the property I am setting has no hooks or getters or setters, the object is fully initialized, and the fields I am using in the calculation are all there.

However, I am getting an infuriating EXC_BREAKPOINT error with no other details.

I suppose it's possible that this is a multithreaded access problem, but I see only empty stacks in all of the other threads.

**Error Breakpoint**:

[image: Error Breakpoint]

**Debugger Values**:

[image: Both fields populated]

**Call Stack** (these are all set or didSet):

[image]

Comment: did you try to set there anything else? like just 1 to play with it?

Comment: What happens if you click continue? In older versions of Xcode I sometimes saw "ghost" breakpoints that weren't listed in the IDE but if you went to the command line and listed breakpoints it showed them. I had to use the command line to delete the unwanted breakpoints. (This happened when I added breakpoints in the IDE and then tried to remove them.) I haven't seen that for several versions though.

Comment: @DuncanC continuing the execution does nothing - it stays at the same point.

Comment: @Lu_ there is no error when I set it to a constant (non-random) value

Comment: Is totalBytes 0 by any chance? Could be a divide-by-zero error.

Comment: @DuncanC There's literally a check for that in OP's pic

Comment: So there is. Derp...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting an integer overflow because you are multiplying 22,667,272 by 99.  Use Int64 rather than Int.

The largest value you can store in a 32 bit integer is 2,147,483,647. 22,667,272 * 99 is 2,244,059,928, so you get an integer overflow.  The size of an `Int` will vary from architecture to architecture, so your code will work on a 64 bit device but not on a 32 bit.  If you use Int64 explicitly you will avoid the overflow.

```
let totalBytes = Int64(self.bytesTotal)
let uploaded = Int64(self.bytesUploaded)

self.percentComplete = Int(1 + 99 * uploaded / totalBytes)
```

Comment: Wow I feel really stupid now! I could also just use floats for the division.